# Light Box in appcelerator alloy

Tags: appcelerator-alloy

I am new in appcelerator. I want to create a light box in appcelerator alloy. can anyone give some reference for that. I have a url, and when click it a light box appear with some description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget to create a LightBox (or look at the code to see how it works to create your own) : http://gitt.io/component/com.alfaqeir.lightbox